# Rails Link_to CSS ID Not Allowing CSS Changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css

I've been on the ruby on rails guide and its specified to write the link_to's that have a css id as:

`<%= link_to "About", about_path, id: "third" %>`

I've also tried:

`<%= link_to ("About", :id => "third"), about_path %>`

This is all well and good as the link works etc, although when I modify my css in the application.css file, no changes happen to the link with id `third`. I am trying to change the margin value and when i do, the link does not move.

Any reason why the css changes aren't showing?

Here is my Css for the third id

`#third {
    margin-top:-10px;
}`

Comment: did you check in inspect element that.. it actually give id to that link..??

Answer (score 1):

There may be couple of reason for that, and I suggest you to use inspect element for that. some of the reasons are.

1) There may be more that one elements with the same Id present on the Dom. if this is the case then you need to make the id uniq.

2) The css might be overrided by any other css applied, you can check this by inspect element.

3) you can also try !important with your css to force apply.

```
#third {
    margin-top:-10px !important;
}
```

4)  Try by applying other css like change color etc, might be your element has no effect on margin-top -10px;

Hope this help!

Comment: thankyou, unfortunately i tried everything there and none worked, there is only one element with id= third, there isnt other css code that is overriding and the !important does not work. thanks anyway mate

Comment: did you check the css file on which you write your css, is loading?

Comment: It is loading, as the whole page is styled properly, apart from that one element with id third

Comment: can you please try by applying other css like change color etc, might be your element has no effect on margin-top -10px;

Comment: Hmm yes I just tried color:red; and it seems to work. Must be just that the margin is unable to be changed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Inline elements don't support negative margin. Try to use relative position instead:

```
position: relative;
top: -10px;
```